# Changing a string to a Char array

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char

Once a value is stored as a String, how can you loop through string and assign each value to a char array? The occurrences of every vowel in array must also be counted.

This is my current code:

```
public class Part1_5 {

  /**
   * Method that gets user name and stores it as a string. Each value then
   * assign to a char array. no of vowels are counted and no of each printed
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Setting up scanner
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // declaring string for name
    String userName = null;

    // declaring ints to hold total no of each vowel
    int totalOfA = 0;
    int totalOfE = 0;
    int totalofI = 0;
    int totalofO = 0;
    int totalofU = 0;

    // Get user input for name
    System.out.println("Please enter your Name...");
    userName = scanner.nextLine();

    for (int loop = 0; loop < userName.length(); loop++) {

      // declaring char array
      char[] letter = userName.toCharArray();

      if (userName.charAt(0) == 'a') {

        totalOfA++;

      }

    }

    System.out.println(totalOfA);

  }

}
```

Comment: A String is basically a char array with a few extra details. But yeah... it's basically a char array already.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The inital part of the question is: "Loop through the string and assign each value to a char array". I was wondering how to do this within my code, or has it already been done?

Comment: Using your way of coding it (while Nick G's way is definitely better, it may be a little too advanced for you, just yet), delete `char[] letter = userName.toCharArray();` and replace `if (userName.charAt(0) == 'a') {` with `if (userName.charAt(loop) == 'a') {` as suggested by pobrelkey. Now you've gotta do the same (if-condition and counting with `loop` as the index) for the remaining vowels. Note that this current implementation only captures `a`, and not `A`. You could fix this by writing `if (userName.charAt(loop) == 'a' || userName.charAt(loop) == 'A') {`. Again, this way isn't pretty. :)

Comment: In the real world you wouldn't need to copy the values in `username` to an array to count the vowels, when you can just use `username.charAt()` to get the character values individually.  And even if for some reason you did want to create an array of `char` from a `String`, you'd just call `yourString.toCharArray()`.  On the other hand, if your professor is making you write unnecessary code just to show you know how to instantiate an array and address its elements, that's another matter...

Comment: I have got my solution now thanks a lot everyone! If you don't mind me asking,  is there any section on stack overflow where I could write answers for novices like myself for content I am familiar with? I would like to be giving answers for questions I know rather than just always receiving them! lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the counting variable in the `for loop` to specify the position in the `userName` `String` to count up the vowels.

Also, you don't even need a `char array` for the method that you're doing. But if you did need one, you should define it before you start the `for loop`. Why create it so many times?

You asked how to loop through the `String` and assign each value to a `char array`, but you don't need to do that: you can simply do what you did, `char[] letter = userName.toCharArray();`.

```
public class Part1_5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Setting up scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // declaring string for name
        String userName = null;

        // declaring ints to hold total no of each vowel
        int totalOfA = 0,totalOfE = 0,totalofI = 0,totalofO = 0,totalofU = 0;

        // Get user input for name
        System.out.println("Please enter your Name...");
        userName = scanner.nextLine();

        // declaring char array (declare it once, before the loop)
        char[] letter = userName.toCharArray();

        for (int loop = 0; loop < userName.length(); loop++) {

            // check and count for any vowel at every iteration of the loop
            if (userName.charAt(loop) == 'a')
                totalOfA++;
            else if (userName.charAt(loop) == 'e')
                totalOfE++;
            else if (userName.charAt(loop) == 'i')
                totalOfI++;
            else if (userName.charAt(loop) == 'o')
                totalOfO++;
            else if (userName.charAt(loop) == 'u')
                totalOfU++;
        }
        System.out.println(totalOfA);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "stackoveflow";
char[] aa= str.toCharArray();
```

And to directly get a char from string, you can use:

```
str.charAt(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about iterating over (and counting) all characters in a String?

Does the count of the vowels have to be case sensitive?

```
Map<Character, Integer> count = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
char[] chars = "this is a test".toCharArray();
for (char curr : chars){
    Integer tmp = count.get(curr);
    if (tmp == null){ tmp = new Integer(0); }
    tmp++;
    count.put(curr, tmp);    
}
System.out.println(count.get("a".charAt(0)));
System.out.println(count.get("e".charAt(0)));
System.out.println(count.get("i".charAt(0)));
System.out.println(count.get("o".charAt(0)));
System.out.println(count.get("u".charAt(0)));
```

Which gives you...

```
1
1
2
null
null
```

Handling null is trivial - e.g. result == null ? 0 : result

**Edit: Improved with 100% more case insensitivity!!**

```
Map<Character, Integer> count = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for (char curr :  "this IS a test".toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
    Integer tmp = count.get(curr);
    count.put(curr, tmp == null ? 1 : ++tmp);
}
```

And the same thing, but in Groovy...

```
def count = "this IS a test".toLowerCase().collect().countBy{it}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (userName.charAt(loop) == 'a') {
```